# Blackberry browsing problem

Tags: java, url, browser, blackberry, java-me

I was trying to open a browser session on a blackberry mobile using j2me. I searched the net and I found this solution:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.google.com");
```

But I had a little problem. The `Browser` word causes a compiler error, so I think there is a library that needs to be imported.

Does anyone know where I can get that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google for `blackberry browser getdefaultsession` yields: [net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/Browser.html)

Comment: yes thank u so much but i already did that but i dont know what to import

Comment: i'm using netbeans and i'm new with it so would u plz tell me what to import to identify the class Browser

Comment: are you looking for the java import statement needed?  That would be `import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser`

Comment: however, maybe your problem is that you are using NetBeans?  As far as I am aware, NetBeans is not a supported platform for developing for the BlackBerry.  You need to use either RIM's JDE or Eclipse.  RIM's site about developing Java apps for BlackBerry: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/